# how to upload files to the second hdd of my linux root server

Tags: linux, mount, aria2

I knew this is a quite simple question, but I'm new in using a quite big server with two 4TB HDDs and I want to learn a lot about it.

I've got a php script that runs as a cron. The script calls a shell command (aria2c) that downloads a file from a ftp-server and put the file into a specific folder on my server. This works fine since months. The files on the server have to be downloadable for users.

But now we mounted a second hdd to get more space for files. As I can see, the mounting was successful.

Two days ago the quota of HDD1 was reached and the script threw errors. Up to this time, I believed that the upload will automatically switch to hdd2. But this was wrong! Here my question arises. **How can I upload files to HDD2 and make it downloadable for users.?**

My upload command for aria2c is:

```
aria2c --ftp-user $username --ftp-passwd $password -c -p -t 100 -s 2 --max-connection-per-server 1 --max-download-limit $speedLimit --allow-overwrite=true --file-allocation none --summary-interval 0 ftp://$server/$remfile -o files/$remfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a list of errors, I found a solution for my problem:

1. the path to my second hdd is.  **/mnt/disk1** (thanks to NIZ for the hint)
2. include this dir to the **open_basedir** in the **php.ini** like: **[other dirs]:/mnt/disk1**
3. log in with shell and go to the **mnt** dir. Make the dir disk1 writable with e.g. **sudo chmod 777 disk1**
4. write a test.txt with `fopen("/mnt/disk1/text.txt");`
5. The test.txt file can now be downloaded with a download script that includes the absolute path "/mnt/disk1/test.txt"

I hope that I could helb anyone who is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your command you download the file in directory named "files". I suppose that it is in your main HDD "/". Run a "df" command to see where your second HDD is mounted and change the output path to something like:

```
/media/HDD2/files/$remfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have found the disk1 directory . But I do not know how to access this directory out of my php script. Because the path points out of my website root dir.:

disk1:   **/mnt/disk1**

path of a test.php: **/var/www/vhosts/xxx.de/httpdocs/test/test.php**

mnt and var are in the same root directory